# Java - should I use new() in Setters or not?

Tags: java, reference, new-operator, setter

I see that a default `setX` function just uses `X = _x`, but in Java wouldn't it be just a reference to the `_x` object?

Shouldn't I use `X = new X(_x)` instead?

I truly looked for an answer, and haven't found one.

Comment: "wouldn't it be just a reference to the _x object" Yes. "Shouldn't I use X = new X(_x) instead?" depends if a) `X` has such a constructor, b) you actually need a new instance (e.g. as a defensive copy).

Comment: YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(); yourClass.setX(_x). You can post your code?

Comment: What's wrong with a reference to an existing object instance if that's what you need? Whether you need a new instance or not depends on the scenario.

Comment: @MehrajMalik The question is general, and hence I find it pretty clear. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be semantically correct, `_x` isn't an object, it's a parameter, and it's referring to an object.  And yes, afterwards your `X` will be a copy of that reference, so it will point to the same object.

But usually that is exactly what you want to achieve.  You don't want to spawn new objects whenever you set a value.  And often you explicitly want it to be exactly the same object.

It's only if the calling site considers its version of the object as private property, that it's its responsability to produce and set a copy instead.

Answer (score 3):

The name setter implies: setting a field.

That method isn't called storeCopyOf(), is it?

Of course you can use *new* (in case the corresponding class offers a copy constructor),  but doing so in a setter is not common practice. And as shown, doing so is very misleading given the meaning that the name setX() communicates.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't I use `X = new X(_x)` instead?

No, you shouldn't. A user of your API expects to set exactly the given instance, not a copy of it.

You could validate this incoming instance by throwing an exception if it doesn't fit your needs, but it's really unclear to set a copy.

*Probably, you may want to return a value from a getter by using this approach. Returning a copy of an inner field (of a reference type) is a good technique to maintain immutability.*

Answer (score 1):

We use `setter` (and `getter`) method to implement [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Example :

```
private String myField; //"private" means access to this is restricted

public String getMyField()
{
     //include validation, logic, logging or whatever you like here
    return this.myField;
}
public void setMyField(String value)
{
     //include more logic
     this.myField = value;
}
```

Someone who is using your `API`s, will pass these value according to need, like :

```
obj.setMyField("myvalue");
```

Answer (score 1):

If x is a primitive type, then there is no need to recreate the value with a copy constructor as changes to its value elsewhere won't affect the local copy.

If you are setting a mutable (changeable) object, but you don't want your copy changed, then yes you should use a copy constructor in your setter. However I'd hesitate to call that setting, it's more like a `saveCopy(_x);`